# Does SQL Server 2016 Support Windows Server 2016 Essentials?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2016

The Requirements for SQL Server 2016 list the following operating systems as being supported:

- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2016 Standard
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
- Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
- Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2012 Standard
- Windows Server 2012 Essentials
- Windows Server 2012 Foundation
- Windows 10 Home
- Windows 10 Professional
- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Windows 8.1
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Windows 8.1 Enterprise
- Windows 8
- Windows 8 Pro
- Windows 8 Enterprise

Windows Server 2016 Essentials appears to be missing from this list. Is this an ommision on Microsofts part - 2012 Essentials is supported...

What specifically in Server 2016 Essentials would cause issues running SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Well, I can see WS2016Essential on the list:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server